# How to get timed input in python?

Tags: python, input, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am working on a project where I want to convert speech to text. So I am using SpeechRecogniser for this.

Speech recogniser stops functioning after a pause is detected by it, but I do not want this to happen. I want the user to press 'q' or 'Q' to stop speech to text.

Here is what I have tried,

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import threading

r = sr.Recognizer()


def disp(text):
    print(text)

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    transcript = open('transcript.txt', 'w')
    print('Start speaking')
    while(True):
        audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            transcript.writelines(text)

        except:
            print('Inaudible. Try again.')

        timer = threading.Timer(2.0, disp(text))
        timer.start()

        q = input()

        try:
            if q == 'q' or q == 'Q':
                print('Ending transcript')
                timer.cancel()
                break

        except NoneType:
            continue
```

If the user opts to quit within 2 seconds of them stopping to speak, only then I want it to stop  the process.

The error I am getting,

```
Start speaking
hello this is path
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1182, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

q
Ending transcript
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is how to pass the function **dist** to **threading.Timer**:
Timer class take a function callable and you send None (result of disp()).

Try this:

```
        timer = threading.Timer(2.0, disp, args=(text,))
```